# Which HTML editor with image upload/embed function is the easiest to integrate in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, wysiwyg

If you say TinyMCE, kindly provide example how to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer FCKedtior which is easily integrate with Coldfusion, PHP and others. It has own built-in coding for PHP. And you need to configure a few lines to integrate with your system.

http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/PHP

Comment: Chose Javascript method from this tutorial and it worked. http://www.jbcrawford.net/archives/159
Needed a little tweaks on "paths" though.

Answer (score 0):

I think tinyMCE is quite capable though I haven´t used it with cakePHP.  There is a lot of config examples on the tinyMCE website, for instance:  [this from the documentation](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:PHP_Example)

Answer (score 0):

There are available TinyMCE helper for CakePHP. You can download Croogo and search for TinyMce inside the pacekage